# Google Maps plugin - Create map from front-end form

Tags: plugins, google-maps

I'm using the [Google Maps plugin for Craft](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Google-Maps-for-Craft) and I'm trying to generate the map via a front-end entry form using address fields but I can't seem to get this to work. If I go into the admin and save the entry I can get it to generate using a Google Map field.

Does anyone have any ideas?